# Mongoengine - how to atomically update a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, updates, mongoengine

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class TestDoc(Document):
    name = StringField()
    friends = ListField(StringField())
    address_book = DictField()
```

And I wish to atomically update the address_book field whenever the friends list changes. How can I modify both fields in an atomic operation? I can't find any modifier in the documentation:

https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates

that makes atomic update for dictionaries.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When every you do a `$push` or `$pull` from the `friends` field you will also in the same update have to modify the `address_book` eg:

```
TestDoc(name="Sue", friends=["Bob", "Sarah"], 
        address_book={"Bob": "1 the farm", "Sarah": "Owl house"}).save()

TestDoc.objects(name="Sue").update(pull__friends="Bob", 
                                   unset__address_book__Bob=1)
```

Comment: Oooh, I see: so you access the element of the dictionary called Bob using __...Ah, I should've thought of that! Many thanks again, Ross!

Comment: Ross, I have another question: what if the address_book dictionary field would look like: address_book={"Mary" : {"parents_address" : ["12 OceanWay", "13 Long Rd"]} , "Bob" : {"work_address" : ["45 CentralRd"]}} ? How could I atomically update for example "12 OceanWay" to change it to "13 OceanWay"?